# Reformatting a hash with new keys (as symbols) based on date format

Tags: ruby

I need to convert this:

```
[{"day"=>"2014-02-01", "users"=>1234},
 {"day"=>"2014-02-02", "users"=>2234},
 {"day"=>"2014-02-03", "users"=>3234},
 {"day"=>"2014-02-04", "users"=>4234}]
```

into this:

```
[{:x=>1, y:=>1234},
 {:x=>2, y:=>2234},
 {:x=>3, y:=>3234},
 {:x=>4, y:=>4234}]
```

Comment: It's really important that you show your code written to solve the problem. Without that it appears you're simply asking others to do your work for you, which wouldn't be fair at all, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = [{"day"=>"2014-02-01", "users"=>1234}, {"day"=>"2014-02-02", "users"=>2234}, {"day"=>"2014-02-03", "users"=>3234}, {"day"=>"2014-02-04", "users"=>4234}]

a.map.with_index(1) { |h,i| { :x => i, :y => h['users'] } }
# => [{:x=>1, :y=>1234}, {:x=>2, :y=>2234}, {:x=>3, :y=>3234}, {:x=>4, :y=>4234}]
```

Comment: That's great! Except I actually need the x values to increment regardless of the date. The sample you gave is correct, but it gets the day # instead of just counting 1,2,3,4...

Thanks!

Comment: @devpreneur Even shorter :)

Comment: You can set an offset: `a.map.with_index(1) { |h, i| { x: i, ... } }`

Comment: One of many variants: `a.size.times.map { |i| {x: i+1, y: a[i]["users"]} }
`.